# Firebase runtime crash - FIRInstanceIDConfig

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added the Firebase SDK manually to my project. (Can't use cocoapods due to configuration issues.)

I use the following frameworks

```
FirebaseCore.framework        
FirebaseInstanceID.framework
Firebasemessageing.framework
```

In the `AppDelegate` I have imported the following:

```
#import "Firebase.h
#import <FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h>
#import <FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>
```

If I make reference to

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
```

I get a runtime crash with the following error:

**Error message in the console:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   fira_UTF32Length]:

However if I comment out that and make reference to this line of code

```
 [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]
```

I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FIRInstanceIDConfig setAllowGCMRegistrationWithoutAPNSToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have added all the required frameworks I can think of, yet still getting this issue.

**Edit**

The complete list of Frameworks linked to the project:

- Fabric,
- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseCore
- FirebaseInstanceID
- FirebaseMessaging
- GoogleToolboxForMac
- GTMSessionFetcher
- Protobuf
- FirebaseAppIndexing
- WebKit
- LocalAuthentication
- Security
- ImageIO
- AssetLibrary
- CoreData
- UIKit
- libc++.tbd
- libsqlite3.tbd
- libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
- libAdidAccess.a

**The stack trace:**

This is the thread where it crashes is:

```
    0   ???                                 0x00000001057f0a44 0x0 + 4387179076,
1   MyApp                            0x000000010050f220 main + 0,
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x0000000181363400 abort + 140,
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000180e2d2d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0,
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000180e4acc0 <redacted> + 0,
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180e58844 <redacted> + 124,
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000180e4766c <redacted> + 16,
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000180e476dc _ZSt9terminatev + 64,
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180e587a0 <redacted> + 0,
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001015bd22c _dispatch_client_callout + 36,
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001015be048 dispatch_once_f + 116,
11  MyApp                            0x00000001006484d4 +[FIRInstanceID instanceID] + 56,
12  MyApp                            0x00000001000fa880 -[BBAppDelegate connectToFcm] + 52,
13  MyApp                            0x00000001000f3ac8 -[BBAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 356,
14  UIKit                               0x000000018835b4c0 <redacted> + 1152,
15  UIKit                               0x000000018855ec48 <redacted> + 2744,
16  UIKit                               0x0000000188573104 <redacted> + 48,
17  UIKit                               0x000000018855b7ec <redacted> + 168,
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000183ff792c <redacted> + 36,
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000183ff7798 <redacted> + 176,
20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000183ff7b40 <redacted> + 56,
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823ceb5c <redacted> + 24,
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823ce4a4 <redacted> + 524,
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001823cc0a4 <redacted> + 804,
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001822fa2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444,
25  UIKit                               0x00000001883417b0 <redacted> + 608,
26  UIKit                               0x000000018833c534 UIApplicationMain + 208,
27  MyApp                            0x000000010050f2c4 main + 164,
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001812dd5b8 <redacted> + 4
)
```

Comment: What frameworks exactly are you linking? Do you have more complete backtraces?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Are you intending to use both FirebaseAnalytics and GoogleAnalytics?

Comment: Can do without FirbaseAnalytics I think.

Answer (score 14):

In **project** Go to **Build Setting** -> Double click on **Other Linker Flags** ->click the plus(**+**)button from bottom add -ObjC and press enter. Hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have this flag already set. Hasn't helped unfortunately

Comment: This helped me, thanks! (I had also problem with missing category and method `fira_UTF32Length`)

Comment: this also solved my problem. i can't use cocoapods since i'm supporting a really old project where i somehow can't get modules to work. adding the -ObjC flag to the other link flags resolved my crash (which would only occur if FIRAnalytics was referenced in the code, even if it wasn't executed).

Comment: Also don't forget to add the `GoogleToolboxForMac.framework` to the project. Otherwise you will get an error about the `gtm_dataByGzippingData` selector being missing from an instance.